# Android Button Top/Bottom Padding not working in Android 4?

Tags: android, android-layout

When using a smaller text size on a button with a background gradient the button shrinks as expected on Android 2.2 but not on Android 4.  The only way I could get it to work is to turn the button into a TextView and set up a click event on it.  I have seen mention of TextViews having this issue but those work as expected for me.

I have seen it working as expected on an Android 2.2 phone, but the button remaining full height on an Android 4.0.4 phone and on an Android 4.2.2 emulator.

Please let me know what I might be doing wrong. This example uses all the defaults from the new app wizard in Eclipse (Juno).

Note: for my real app I was using

```
android:padding="4dp"
```

which made the TextView look nice (didn't affect the Button) but I used 0dp for this example to exaggerate the issue.

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_gradient"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_gradient"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_gradient"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_gradient"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</LinearLayout>
```

button_gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#0000BB"
        android:endColor="#E0E0E0"
        android:angle="90"/>
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using LinearLayout you can use RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="20dp"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gradient"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gradient"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gradient"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gradient"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

Comment: Thanks PiyushMishra. I tried what you suggested and it acts the same way. I gave each element an id and used the layout_below attribute to have the elements stack up like a LinearLayout so I can see them and they are still over padded above and below the text. FWIW, I see the problem being exhibited in the Graphical Layout when viewing the layout in Eclipse (Juno) even though it works correctly on Android 2.2.